# $L^2$-extension of solutions of elliptic equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I'm dealing with a problem characterizing $L^2$-extension of solutions of elliptic equations. The model is as follows. Suppose $L$ is an elliptic operator over $\mathbb{R}^n$, and we assume the vector space $H$ of global $L^2$-solutions of $L\psi=0$ is of finite dimension. Consider a disk $B_R$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we are interested in the infinite dimensional space $\mathscr{H}=L^2(B_R)\cap KerL$. Clearly we will have a bounded operator $r:H\to\mathscr{H}$ by restriction. My question is: do we have any condition characterizing the image of $r$, i.e. a property for $\psi\in\mathscr{H}$ that will assure it is given by restriction of some global solution. Some more assumptions are allowed, e.g. $L$ satisfies unique continuation property s.t. $r$ is injective.

I know the question is too general. So I'm just hoping for any related results or theories, which might be an inspirational example for my special case of Dirac operators.